# Getting my first Spring webapp to work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller that gets an ID from a form in search.jsp. I want it to redirect to entitydemo.jsp, which should be able to access EntityDemo and output its attributes. How do I do that? Do I need to use redirect and put EntityDemo as a session attribute somehow?

```
@Controller
public class SearchEntityController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public EntityDemo getEntityDemoByID(@ModelAttribute("search") Search search, BindingResult result) {
    EntityDemo entityDemo = null;
    if (search.getId() != null) {
      int id = Integer.parseInt(search.getId());
      entityDemo = DBHelper.getEntityDemo(id);
    }
    return entityDemo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using 2 methods in my controller - one to display the form and another for the search results

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SearchEntityController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public void searchForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute(new Search());
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/entitydemo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public void showSearchResult(@ModelAttribute Search search, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("entityDemo", getEntityDemo(search));
  }

  // code to load entity here
}
```

(Search is a class with an `int id` and accessors)

Form in search.jsp:

```
<form:form action="entitydemo" commandName="search">
    ID: <form:input path="id" />
</form:form>
```

Showing results in entitydemo.jsp:

```
<core:out value="${entityDemo.foo}" /> <br/>
<core:out value="${entityDemo.bar}" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have some class named `EntityDemo` which has `Getters` and `Setters` for all the fields, I think you should do something like so:

```
@Controller
public class SearchEntityController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView getEntityDemoByID(@ModelAttribute("search") Search search, BindingResult result) {
    EntityDemo entityDemo = null;
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (search.getId() != null) {
      int id = Integer.parseInt(search.getId());
      entityDemo = DBHelper.getEntityDemo(id);
      model.put("entityDemo", entityDemo);
    }

    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(pageIWantToRedirectTo), model);
  }
}
```

Then, in your JSP, you can use `JSTL` and do something like this: `${entityDemo.name}`, where `name` is a field I am assuming that the `EntityDemo` class has together with an appropriate `Getter`, this being `public String getName(){return this.name;}`.

To my knowledge, Controller methods do not return entire objects, they either return `String` values which denote the name of the view, such as `\foo\bar\myPage.jsp` or else, entire `ModelAndView` objects (there are 2 types of objects, one of them has `portlet` in its full name and the other has `servlet`. In this case you must use the one that has `servlet` in its full name. Just for clarity, when I say full name, I mean the name which includes the package within which it resides. If memory serves me well the one you are looking for is in `springframework...servlet.ModelAndView` or something like that.

EDIT: If you want to redirect upon submit, then, you will need to make 2 controllers, one which will render the form and the other which will redirect once the form is submitted.

Regarding your JSP Page, you should have an xml file name `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. The name could be different, depending on your configurations in `web.xml`, but they all have the structure of `<servletname>-servlet.xml`. There should be a property named `viewResolver` (Although this should be the case, certain IDE's do not populate much for you. On the other hand, IDE's such as Netbeans set up most of the initial configuration for you). This is another controller which acts upon your `views`. What it does is that it automatically appends items before and after your `view` name which you specify in your controller. Usually it appends a prefix of `pages/jsp/` and a suffix of `.jsp`. So, if you have a page with the following path `pages/jsp/myPage.jsp`, all you need to pass in your controller would be `myPage`. The full path to the page will be constructed by the view resolver. If you pass in the whole URL, it will still keep on adding stuff so the page still won't be found even though you specified a correct path.

Comment: @Michael: I have modified my answer. XML files in spring are highly important and in most cases, will be the reason why your solution is not working. Once that you get the hang of it you will find that Spring will speed up your development.

Comment: Cheers. I've finally got it working. I'm actually using one controller with 2 methods - one that puts the class representing the form on the Model (for the form page) and one that loads the entity and puts it on the Model (for the results page).

Comment: @Michael: Yes you are correct, you can have multiple methods using the same class (controller). Glad my answer helped.